# I can't populate table from postgres to django model

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have following problem. I've created table 'users' using postgres database, then I've created model:

```
from django.db import models

class Users(models.Model):
 name= models.CharField(max_length=30)
 surmane=models.CharField(max_length=50)
 city=models.CharField(max_length=60)
 country=models.CharField(max_length=30)
 street=models.CharField(max_length=60)
 code=models.CharField(max_length=30)
 email=models.CharField(max_length=30)
 def __str__(self):
  return self.name
```

After I made syncdb, the model-table occurs in the database but it is not populated in data from the table 'users'. Why is that? No error occured during synchronization. Everything gone well exept that thing. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Django provides a table auth_users for storing user data in the database. If you want to make your own User model, you can do so either by extending the class User in django.contrib , or make a separate model for User Profile having a foreign key as User .

Secondly , if you want to create table with data before syncdb, you have to make the table as the same name as the _users , so that after the syncdb , django won't create a new table in the database , instead use your table.
Hope it solves your doubt.

Comment: Thanks Mohit Bagga, but in that (second) case I have an error: column name _users.id doesn't exists. This is because my primary key kolumn is named id_user and in the model one's doesn't explicity give id attribute. What to do in that situation?

Comment: You can specify a field as primary key explicitly by using primary_key=True [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields). You have to create auth_user as your user table , and not _user . Sorry for typo